# .NET Properties

Tags: c#, .net, properties

Can someone help me to figure out how can I achieve following:

```
PersonalInfo info = new PersonalInfo();
info.Contact.Name = "name";
info.Contact.Telephone = "2323232";
```

Thanks.

---

The following was achieved.

```
PersonalInfo info = new PersonalInfo(); 
info.Contact.Name = "name"; 
info.Contact.Telephone = "2323232";
```

But in the case of following, what should I do?

```
PersonalInfo info = new PersonalInfo(); 
info.Contact.Name = "name"; 
info.Contact.Telephone = "2323232";
info.Contact.Office.Address = "Sweden"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You already achieved (typed) it. What's the actual question? Di Oyvind guess correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Contact{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Telephone {get;set;}
}

public class PersonalInfo{
  public Contact Contact {get;set;}
  public PersonalInfo(){
    this.Contact = new Contact();
  }
}

var info = new PersonalInfo();
info.Contact.Name = "name";
info.Contact.Telephone = "2323232";
```

;)

Comment: You have to add a constructor that creates the `Contact` (or don't use auto-properties)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Test()
{
    PersonalInfo pi = new PersonalInfo();

    pi.Contact = new Contact();

    pi.Contact.Name = "test";
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Telephone {get;set}
}

public class PersonalInfo
{
    public Contact Contact {get;set;}
}
```

If you want to automatically instantiate the Contact details add this constructor to the personalInfo class:

```
    public PersonalInfo()
    {
        this.Contact = new Contact();
    }
```

Comment: Really don't like that you are suggesting that he uses public fields instead of properties in his classes.

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen -  Updated, Was just a quick example :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PersonalInfo
{
    public Contact contact = new Contact(); 
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```